# Dotnet Core project ran into error after upgrading Angular CLI and Core to the latest version

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am new to Open source technologies so I am still trying to understand how npm, node and everything works.

- Dotnet version : 2.2.102
- Node version : v11.14.0
- NPM version : 6.5.0

I had created a Single Page Angular project with ASP.NET Core using dotnet CLI. Today I decided to upgrade the Angular Core and Angular CLI.

Upgrade details:

- Angular core : from 6.1.10 to 7.2.15
- Angular CLI : from 6.0.0 to 7.3.9

After successful upgrade, I also ran npm audit fix as a habit but it returned with 0 dependencies fixed and I didn't care much about it.

Then I executed the command "dotnet build" which said Build Succeeded.
So I moved on to run "dotnet run" command and that's when it started showing errors :

> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>         User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\RecursionParameter\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys'
>   as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest. info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>         Starting @angular/cli on port 4777... Hosting environment: Development Content root path: F:\Daily Usage\Projects\dotnet
>   core\checklist Now listening on: https://localhost:5001 Now listening
>   on: http://localhost:5000 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut
>   down. info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>
> > checklist@0.0.0 start F:\Daily Usage\Projects\dotnet core\checklist\ClientApp
> >     ng serve "--port" "4777"
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4777, open your browser on http://localhost:4777/ **
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>         Date: 2019-05-20T12:14:01.608Z Hash: 0c8a551fd7e094fbe22d Time: 4701ms chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.96 kB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map
>   (polyfills) 92.4 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {runtime} runtime.js,
>   runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {styles}
>   styles.css, styles.css.map (styles) 126 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk
>   {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 327 kB [initial] [rendered]
>
> `fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]`
>
> `fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]`
>         ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/injector.d.ts(68,70): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(317,32): error TS1005: ')' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(317,33): error TS1003: Identifier expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(317,83): error TS1005: ';' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(317,84): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(317,98): error TS1005: '=>' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(328,16): error TS1109: Expression expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(372,12): error TS1109: Expression expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(372,28): error TS1005: ']' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(372,29): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(372,30): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(372,31): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(372,40): error TS1005: ':' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(372,70): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(383,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(383,29): error TS1005: ']' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(383,30): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(383,31): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(383,32): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(383,41): error TS1005: ':' expected.
>         node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/definition.d.ts(383,52): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
>         i ∩╜ówdm∩╜ú: Failed to compile.

I have no idea what happened here.

Comment: This is not a problem with ASP.NET Core. Go into the `ClientApp` folder and run `ng serve` there. That might help you to track the error down.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to resolve a false fail when generating angular bundles for SPA in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840557/how-to-resolve-a-false-fail-when-generating-angular-bundles-for-spa-in-net-core/75234519#75234519)