# How to resolve a false fail when generating angular bundles for SPA in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

When I execute the application I'm getting two red fails as shown below. Usually, when there's an error with types or otherwise.

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
> - Generating browser application bundles...
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
> ÔêÜ Browser application bundle generation complete.

The application seem runs ok I experience no failure in its operation. When I build it with *ng build --aot*, everything works dandy.

The issue seems to be the exit code returned in the Angular CLI. Is there anyway to fix or override this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65465740/asp-net-core-net-5-angular-11-build-error-on-empty-project Probably just a benign nonzero exit code from some process. Not much we can say about without a repro.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm getting this in a vanilla project, so it seemed needless to set up a repo. But I think I might, just to make sure there's nothing weird with my system. You're referring to a link to GitHub or such, right? I don't want to get bashed for not posting the code here.

Comment: An issue with Angular projects, it writes progress messages to the error stream.  "ÔêÜ" looks like more sloppy fit-and-finish.  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21793

Comment: @HansPassant I strongly dislike those small glitches. Not critical enough to fix ASAP but accumulating over time to a load of BS, hence hurting the framework. Never the less, I appreciate your comment and I'd call it an actual answer. Would you care to repost it as such, please?

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404659/).

Comment: Any news on this topic? Are there any plans of Angular / MS to fix it? I ran into the same issue...

Comment: @Chris Regrettably, no. The issue is regarded as very low prio, so no attention will be devoted to resolving it. Furthermore, I got the impression that it's not a bug **within** any of the involved systems but rather a lack of compatibility **between** systems. And, as many times before, each faction assess their own approach as the correct one, expecting the counter-part to create a remedy. That is not going to happen unless it doesn't become a huge obstacle. And given that most devs don't even notice it, let alone are bothered by it, you can IMHO consider it the final state and live with it.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]”* error

To get detailed information regarding to the problem causing this error run the app via

`npm start` instead of `dotnet run`.

Then if the error message indicates something e.g. missing packages, you may need to install the missing package(s) and after the problem is fixed you can use:

`dotnet run`