# Trying to Run Angular 9 Web Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, angular, npm

This is my first Angular project.  I can run "npm start" and it starts without error. Here are the errors I am currently getting when I run the application from Visual Studio.  It looks like it sends the same commands but I get these 2 'fail' errors every time.  It opens the browser and does nothing.

> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
>
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
>
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
>
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Hosting environment: Development
>
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Content root path: C:\Users\CF135238\source\repos\COT.DEV.Forf\Forf
>
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
> (node:7664) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
>
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: You have to launch the debug sessies with the **IIS Express** profile. And there's no need to run `npm start` yourself. The webapplication does that for you.

Comment: I understand that - but when I run from IISExpress I get the errors that Iposted.  If I run manually npm start there are no errors from the CLI.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to resolve a false fail when generating angular bundles for SPA in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840557/how-to-resolve-a-false-fail-when-generating-angular-bundles-for-spa-in-net-core/75234519#75234519)

Answer (score 0):

Version compatibility could be the issue in your case. I had that problem and downgrading node js version from 16.8.0 to 14.17.5 resolved my issue.

I also suggest you to use another IDE other then visual studio since it's probably not the right fit for a front end project like Angular. Webstorm and Visual Studio Code are really good for an Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

node js version 14.17.5 is not suppported by Angular Cli , use 14.20.1